# Getting a bitgold prepaid debit card

Tags: debitcard

Can someone tell me what the process is of getting a bitgold prepaid debit card and if I can use it just about anywhere? Does anyone have one of these cards and what is your experience with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting a prepaid card on BitGold is pretty easy, you just have to sign up for an account, make sure you have you deposit 1 GAU (gram of gold) on it and request one by providing an id document and a proof of address.

You can use wherever they accept a MasterCard, pretty much everywhere. I personally tried it in Canada and Italy, and it worked flawlessly.

Please note that, even if you can get GAUs by depositing your BTCs, you cannot currently load them directly on the card, since you can really deposit only on the Dubai Vault, and you cannot load the card with the gold in Dubai.

This is intended, and you can ask to the [customer support](http://support.bitgold.com/customer/portal/emails/new) for more information on why is that so.

As a reference, you can check the [FAQ](http://support.bitgold.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2067276-goldmoney-prepaid-mastercard-general-faqs) on the website.

And [this article](http://support.bitgold.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2069469-apply-for-a-goldmoney-prepaid-mastercard) on how to apply for a prepaid card.

Enjoy your BitGold account :)